# return domain objects from grails constraint validation

Tags: constraints, grails-orm, grails

Is it possible to write your own validator in grails that will return a valid object?

Something like:

```
static constraints = {
    name(validator: {val, obj ->
        if (Drink.findByName(val)) return [Drink.findByName(val)]
    })
}
```

In other words - if the Drink already exists in the DB, just return the existing one when someone does a

new Drink("Coke")

and coke is already in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with a custom validator. It's not really what it was meant for. From the [Grails Reference](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html):

The closure can return:

- `null` or `true` to indicate that the value is valid
- `false` to indicate an invalid value and use the default message code
- a string to indicate the error code to append to the "classname.propertName." string used to resolve the error message. If a field specific message cannot be resolved, the error code itself will be resolved allowing for global error messages.
- a list containing a string as above, and then any number of arguments following it, which can be used as formatted message arguments indexed at 3 onwards. See `grails-app/i18n/message.properties` to see how the default error message codes use the arguments.

An alternative might be to just create a service method that 1) looks for the domain and returns it if it exists, 2) otherwise, saves the domain and returns it.

There's probably a more elegant alternative. Regardless, Grails' constraints mechanism isn't (and shouldn't be) capable of this.

Comment: Ok - thanks! I was hoping for an elegant solution. I saw that reference but wasnt sure if how all inclusive it is

Comment: Yeah. Ultimately, if you use a service or domain method to do this it will be more maintainable in the future, so you're probably better off.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do this from inside the validator, but:

Drink d = Drink.findOrSaveWhere(name: 'Smooth Drink', alcoholLevel: '4.5')